# Add a from in newly added step in checkout page magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, checkout, checkout-page, customize

we follow this [step](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html) to add a new form in checkout page. we need to add some form fields in that newly added steps.

I have updated the `checkout_index_index.xml` file based on shipping-step. But its not working.

Suggest me, which way i need follow.

what I did:

`Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/schedule-on-appointment-view.js`

```
  define(
    [
        'ko',
        'uiComponent',
        'underscore',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
    ],
    function (
            ko,
            Component,
            _,
            stepNavigator
            ) {
        'use strict';
        /**
         *
         * schedule-on-appointment - is the name of the component's .html template,
         * <Hicare_Slot>  - is the name of the your module directory.
         *
         */
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Vendor_Module/schedule_on_appointment'
            },

            //add here your logic to display step,
            isVisible: ko.observable(true),

            /**
             *
             * @returns {*}
             */
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
                // register your step
                stepNavigator.registerStep( 
                        //step code will be used as step content id in the component template
                        'schedule',
                        //step alias
                        null,
                        //step title value
                        'Schedule On Appontment',
                        //observable property with logic when display step or hide step
                        this.isVisible,
                        _.bind(this.navigate, this),
                        /**
                         * sort order value
                         * 'sort order value' < 10: step displays before shipping step;
                         * 10 < 'sort order value' < 20 : step displays between shipping and payment step
                         * 'sort order value' > 20 : step displays after payment step
                         */
                        15
                        );

                return this;
            },

            /**
             * The navigate() method is responsible for navigation between checkout step
             * during checkout. You can add custom logic, for example some conditions
             * for switching to your custom step
             * When the user navigates to the custom step via url anchor or back button we_must show step manually here
             */
            navigate: function () {

                this.isVisible(true);
            },

            /**
             * @returns void
             */
            navigateToNextStep: function () {
                stepNavigator.next();
            }
        });
    }
);
```

`Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/schedule_on_appointment.html`

```
  <!--The 'step_code' value from the .js file should be used-->
<li id="schedule" data-bind="fadeVisible: isVisible">
    <div class="schedule-on-appontment" data-bind="i18n: 'Schedule On Appontment'" data-role="title"></div>
    <div id="checkout-step-title" class="step-content" data-role="content">

        <form data-bind="submit: navigateToNextStep" novalidate="novalidate">
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('schedule_on_appointment_form') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!--/ko-->

            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <div class="primary">
                    <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
                        <span>
                            <!-- ko i18n: 'Next'-->
                            <!-- /ko --></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</li>
```

`Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

```
  <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <!-- The new step you add -->
                                        <item name="schedule-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/view/schedule-on-appointment-view</item>
                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">schedule_on_appointment</item>
                                            <!--To display step content before shipping step "sortOrder" value should be < 1-->
                                            <!--To display step content between shipping step and payment step  1 < "sortOrder" < 2 -->
                                            <!--To display step content after payment step "sortOrder" > 2 -->
                                            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <!--add here child component declaration for your step-->

                                                <item name="schedulesData" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="scheduleAdditional" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">scheduleAdditional</item>
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="delivery_date" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                                                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">schedule_on_appointment_form</item>
                                                                    <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                    <item name="dataScopePrefix" xsi:type="string">delivery_date</item>
                                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="form-fields" xsi:type="array">
                                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/view/schedule-on-appointment-data</item>
                                                                            <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">schedule_on_appointment_form</item>
                                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">

                                                                                <item name="delivery_date" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module/js/view/delivery-date</item>
                                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                        <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">delivery_date</item>
                                                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Hicare_Slot/fields/delivery-date</item>
                                                                                        <item name="options" xsi:type="string"></item>
                                                                                        <item name="id" xsi:type="string">delivery_date</item>
                                                                                        <item name="data-bind" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                            <item name="datetimepicker" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                                        </item>

                                                                                    </item>
                                                                                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">delivery_date.delivery_date</item>
                                                                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Select Date</item>
                                                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item> 
                                                                                    </item>
                                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">10</item>
                                                                                    <item name="id" xsi:type="string">delivery_date</item>

                                                                                </item>

                                                                                <item name="delivery_slot" xsi:type="array">

                                                                                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select</item>
                                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                        <item name="customScope" xsi:type="string">delivery_date</item>
                                                                                        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                                                                                        <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/select</item>
                                                                                        <item name="id" xsi:type="string">delivery_slot</item>
                                                                                        <item name="data-bind" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                            <item name="datetimepicker" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                                        </item>

                                                                                    </item>
                                                                                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">delivery_date.delivery_slot</item>
                                                                                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Time Slots</item>
                                                                                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">checkoutProvider</item>
                                                                                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                                                                                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item> 
                                                                                    </item>
                                                                                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">20</item>
                                                                                    <item name="id" xsi:type="string">delivery_slot</item>

                                                                                </item>

                                                                            </item>
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>                                                    
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument> 
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

`Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/view/schedule-on-appointment-data.js`

```
  define([
    'jquery',
    'ko',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/form'
], function ($, ko, Component) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Vendor_Module/schedule_on_appointment'
        }
    });
});
```

This result only I got:

[image]

I have to add some custom form fields into this section and save it to the database.

Let me know, what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can  add form in template:  Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/template/view/schedule-on-appointment-data.html

Comment: @DSingh, I tried, but it's not working

Comment: have you checked in the private window after clear the cache. I have done the same by adding form in template file.

Comment: @DSingh I tried it's not working. You have any reference or doc for this.